# Table with catogories and multiple sub catogories for each catogory

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to write a new application but I'm stuck. I want to create a database with a table for storing catogories and another one for storing sub categories. I have some ideas about how to create the database/tables but no idea about how I can select categories and all sub categories belonging to that category at once. Can someone help me?

Scenario:

- Table with `Users` identified by ID's.
- Table with `Categories` identified by `ID` and with a foreign key to the `User.ID` (one category can belong to only one user)
- Table with `SubCategories` with foreign keys to the `Category` table it belongs to and the `User.ID` that the `Category` belongs to.

How could I select and display all usernames with belonging categories and sub categories?

Comment: Are your categories only ever one deep? ie parent->sub category and never parent->sub category->sub, sub category?

Comment: Yes, always just User->category->sub. never deeper than the one sub @DanielCasserly

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a query that will give you results like the following:

> **User    Category    SubCategories**
>       Bob  |   Builder  |  BuilderSub1
>       Bob  |   Builder  |  BuilderSub2
>       Jerry | Supervisor | SupervisorSub1
>       Tim  |   Builder  |  BuilderSub3

```
SELECT u.UserName as 'User', c.CategoryName as 'Category', sc.SubcategoryName as 'SubCategories'     
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN Category c ON c.UserId = u.Id 
INNER JOIN Subcategory sc ON
sc.CategoryId = c.Id  
GROUP BY sc.SubcategoryName, c.CategoryName, u.UserName
```

The [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @MegaMark! based on the SELECT statement I was able to create a few tables and now I got it working, just one more thing: I get the username again for every category and I did some research and came to the DISTINCT thingy only that isn't working for me. Any ideas on that last thing?

Comment: You will get back the username for every category... that's expected behavior in this case. (Otherwise, what would be in the 2nd, 3rd, etc rows that you get back for Bob?) DISTINCT won't help because each row you get back *is* distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a foreign key relationship and a JOIN:

```
create table category (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    primary key(id)
);

create table subcategory (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    category_id int,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(category_id) references category(id)
);
```

Here's a sample JOIN:

```
select *
from user
join category
on user.category_id = category.id
join subcategory
on category.id = subcategory.category_id
where user.id = ?
```

Comment: Thank you! But in my case I also have a user ID that all categories/subcategories are linked to, how would I do that? So I basically need to select a user and view all their categories/subcategories

Comment: I'm assuming that you know something about SQL.  You should be able to add more tables to the query.  If you can't, maybe this problem is over your head.

Comment: Yes I know something about SQL. I know how to create relations between tables etc. only selecting data with JOINS is a something I don't master yet

Comment: So I've given you an example.  Time to read more about it and practice to make sure you understand it.